# Qual é o valor padrão do atributo "cursor"?

Tags: css

Qual é o valor padrão do atributo "cursor"?

Eu mudei o valor para `pointer`, mas em determinado caso prefiro voltar para a setinha padrão, porém não sei qual é o valor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O valor `cursor: default` **NÃO** o valor padrão, como a [*primeira resposta*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252797/3635) afirma, o valor padrão na maioria dos user-agents é **`cursor: auto`**.

Note que `default` é um *"tipo de cursor"*, no caso semelhante a esse (depende do sistema operacional ou do pacotes de customização do sistema):

> [image: cursor:default]

O `cursor: auto` faz o navegador (baseado em um estilo interno provavelmente) aplicar um tipo de cursor se baseando no tipo do elemento e para restaurar ao valor "padrão" você pode utilizar o valor `initial` (apesar de `auto` funcionar), no entanto para **outras** propriedades `initial` é o que vai funcionar.

### O valor `initial`

A palavra chave `initial` aplica o valor inicial para uma propriedade de um elemento, isto pode ser usado para qualquer propriedade

Um exemplo do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial):

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

em, a {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Ficará em vermelho.</span>
  <em>Voltará a cor padrão inicial do navegador</em>
  <a href="#">Voltará a cor padrão inicial do navegador</a>
  <span>Em vermelho</span>
</p>
```

Usando com a propriedade `cursor`:

```css
.area-com-cursor-customizado {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.area-com-valor-inicial {
    cursor: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-com-cursor-customizado">
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   
   <div class="area-com-valor-inicial">
       <p>foo bar baz</p>
       <p>foo bar baz</p>
       <p>foo bar baz</p>
       <p>foo bar baz</p>
   </div>
   
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
   <p>foo bar baz</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

O valor padrão é `default`:

```
.exemplo {
   cursor:default;
}
```

Segue exemplo dos possíveis valores para o atributo `cursor`, basta passar o cursor do mouse sobre cada um para visualizar o funcionamento dos mesmos:

```html
<span style="cursor:auto">auto</span><br>
<span style="cursor:crosshair">crosshair</span><br>
<span style="cursor:default">default</span><br>
<span style="cursor:e-resize">e-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:grab">grab</span><br>
<span style="cursor:help">help</span><br>
<span style="cursor:move">move</span><br>
<span style="cursor:n-resize">n-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:ne-resize">ne-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:nw-resize">nw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:pointer">pointer</span><br>
<span style="cursor:progress">progress</span><br>
<span style="cursor:s-resize">s-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:se-resize">se-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:sw-resize">sw-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:text">text</span><br>
<span style="cursor:w-resize">w-resize</span><br>
<span style="cursor:wait">wait</span><br>
<span style="cursor:not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
<span style="cursor:no-drop">no-drop</span><br>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu tinha tentado `normal` e não funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

> A propriedade CSS cursor especifica o cursor do mouse mostrado quando
>   o ponteiro do mouse está sobre um elemento.

O valor inicial dessa propriedede é `auto`, o que acontece é que ele é convertido pelo `browser` em outra propriedade de acordo com seu contexto, geralmente em `default` (A setinha que estamos acostumados a ver).

> `cursor: auto;` O brower determina o cursor para ser exibido baseado
>   no contexto atual.

Links para referência:

[Cursor - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

[Cursor - W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Tem um detalhe interessante: Se o valor for `auto` em um `<a>`, seria o mesmo que usar `pointer`. Isso esclarece perfeitamente qual é o valor padrão do `cursor`, mas a para a setinha o valor é `default`.

Comment: Sim, ele identifica o cursor devido a seu contexto, se você quer forçar a setinha deve definir a propriedade  `default` como citado pelo leandro.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, o padrão do cursor vai depender do contexto.
Para usar a setinha comum você poderia usar `cursor: default`,
mas se quiser o padrão pelo contexto, utilize `cursor: auto`.